# Adding active class to html element doesn`t work

Tags: javascript, function, events

I'm trying to build a slider with active dots and I succeded to do the most of the work but the problem is that active class doesn`t take effect. So at the end of showNews function, I added that line trying to add the class but no effect. Can anyone help me how to add active class to dots when you are at the current page to show black dot?
And when I click on a dot to go to the specified page.[enter link description here][1]

```js
// *Second Slider*
var sliderIndex = 0;

let next2 = document.querySelector(".next2");
let prev2 = document.querySelector(".prev2");

function showNews(n) {
  debugger;
  const slider = document.getElementsByClassName('news');
  const dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
  for (i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
    slider[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    sliderIndex = slider.length - 1;
  }
  if (n > slider.length - 1) {
    sliderIndex = 0
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", " ");
  }
  slider[sliderIndex].style.display = 'block';
  dots[sliderIndex].classList.add(' red')
}
```

```css
#section-three .slideshow-container2 {
  position: relative;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .prev2,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .next2 {
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 black;
          box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 black;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .next2 {
  left: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .prev2 {
  right: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
          transform: rotate(225deg);
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .company-btn,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .industry-btn {
  margin: 1.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
  transition: 0s;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .company-btn:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .industry-btn {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .industry-btn:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news-content,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  height: 600px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news-content p,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content p {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 2rem 8rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news-content h1,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content {
  background: white;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: (1fr)[3];
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[3];
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 1.5rem 6rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .media-room {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .img {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .texter {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .wiew-more {
  color: green;
  -ms-grid-row: 4;
  grid-row: 4;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .wiew-more:hover {
  color: #242121;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 #dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot:hover,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot.active {
  background: black;
}



.active{
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Section-three -->
  <section id="section-three">
    <div class="container slideshow-container2">
      <div class="news">
        <div class="news-content">
          <div class="buttons">
            <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
            <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
          </div>
          <h1>OUR PEOPLE ARE OUT STONGEST ASSET </h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto voluptate fugiat, molestias adipisci
            voluptas
            nisi blanditiis a aliquid accusantium omnis, soluta animi praesentium ipsam fugit? Non ea nisi optio
            dolores.voluptate fugiat, molestias adipisci voluptas
            nisi blanditiis a aliquid accusantium omnis, soluta animi praesentium ipsam fugit? Non ea nisi optio
            dolores.
          </p>
          <a class="my-2 wiew-more" href="#">WIEW MORE</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="news news2">
        <div class="news2-content">
          <div class="buttons">
            <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
            <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
          </div>
          <h1 class="media-room">MEDIA ROOM </h1>
          <div class="img">
            <img src="/Core/img/media.jpg" style="width:500px" alt="">
          </div>
          <p class="texter">London, June 2019 – If you want to enjoy wireless technology while gaming an unnoticeable
            latency is key.
            Sennheiser introduces the GSP 670, Sennheiser's first wireless gaming headset. The GSP 670 gives gamers
            significantly more freedom of movement than wired models. The audio specialist has integrated a proprietary
            low-latency connection that guarantees a reliable and stable transmission with near-zero delay. In addition,
            the GSP 670 offers Sennheiser’s renowned wearing comfort and premium audio performance.

          </p>
          <a class="my-2 wiew-more " href="#">WIEW MORE2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="dots">
        <span class="dot " onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="prev2"></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="next2"></a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Section four -->
  <section id="section-four">
    <div id="section-four-content">
      <h1>CONTACT</h1>
      <div class="IMG">
        <img src="/Core/img/logo.png" style="width: 100px" alt="logo">
      </div>
      <p>Headphone Creative Tehnology LTD</p>
      <p>ADD:No.3 Willow Road London UK Post Code:LO45FR</p>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">
            <p>858-5455-555</p>
            <span><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i></span>
            <p>SERVICE HOTLINE</p>
          </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <p>the_voice@yahoo.com</p>
            <span><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></span>
            <p>E-MAIL</p>
          </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <p>0738-5455-5325</p>
            <span><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i></span>
            <p>TELEPHONE</p>
          </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <p>32 221-5464895</p>
            <span><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i></span>
            <p>FAX</p>
          </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <p>the_voice</p>
            <span><i class="fab fa-skype"></i></span>
            <p>SKYPE</p>
          </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Please add relevant code here as a [mcve], as an [edit] to your question, not links to off-site resources.

Comment: Demos are great but only as support for what actually exists in the question. We shouldn't have to go off site to do an initial review of your issue. Questions should be self contained

Comment: Next time you ask a question, try to make sure everything's hooked up and clean so that it's easy to assist. You have a space in your class assignment, your slider doesn't call `showNews` and you have so much extra stuff on the screen that it's difficult to know what it is  your supposed to be looking at. You could've cut this down much, much more before posting. That being said, you're new - so I understand! Welcome! But do try to be courteous :)

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

Use modular to create a circular array point.

```
 (index + movement + length) % length
```

To make this possible, when the `showNews` function is first called we store an `active` index within it. `this.active` is initially `0` if undefined, then it is assigned the result of the above formula.

```
  if(this.active === undefined) this.active = 0;
  this.active = ( this.active + n + dots.length) % dots.length;
  dots[this.active].classList.add("active");
```

This setup basically makes it so that `showNews(-1)` will move left one or circle to the far right. `showNews(1)` will move right one or circle to the far left.

Once we attach these to your `next2` and `prev2` buttons, voila.

---

### Example:

```js
// *Second Slider*
var sliderIndex = 0;

let next2 = document.querySelector(".next2");
let prev2 = document.querySelector(".prev2");
next2.addEventListener("click", function() { showNews(1); });
prev2.addEventListener("click", function() { showNews(-1); });
function showNews(n) {
  const slider = document.getElementsByClassName('news');
  const dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');

  
  for (i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
    slider[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    sliderIndex = slider.length - 1;
  }
  if (n > slider.length - 1) {
    sliderIndex = 0
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  
  if(this.active === undefined) this.active = 0;
  this.active = ( this.active + n + dots.length) % dots.length;
  dots[this.active].classList.add("active");
  
  slider[sliderIndex].style.display = 'block';
  dots[sliderIndex].classList.add('red')
}
```

```css
#section-three .slideshow-container2 {
  position: relative;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .prev2,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .next2 {
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 black;
          box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 black;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .next2 {
  left: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .prev2 {
  right: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
          transform: rotate(225deg);
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .company-btn,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .industry-btn {
  margin: 1.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
  transition: 0s;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .company-btn:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .industry-btn {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons .industry-btn:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news-content,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  height: 600px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news-content p,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content p {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 2rem 8rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news-content h1,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .news2-content {
  background: white;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: (1fr)[3];
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[3];
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 1.5rem 6rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .buttons {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .media-room {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .img {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .texter {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .wiew-more {
  color: green;
  -ms-grid-row: 4;
  grid-row: 4;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .wiew-more:hover {
  color: #242121;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 #dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot:hover,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot.active {
  background: black;
}



.active{
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Section-three -->
  <section id="section-three">
    <div class="container slideshow-container2">
      <div class="news">
        <div class="news-content">
          <div class="buttons">
            <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
            <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
          </div>
          <h1>OUR PEOPLE ARE OUT STONGEST ASSET </h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto voluptate fugiat, molestias adipisci
            voluptas
            nisi blanditiis a aliquid accusantium omnis, soluta animi praesentium ipsam fugit? Non ea nisi optio
            dolores.voluptate fugiat, molestias adipisci voluptas
            nisi blanditiis a aliquid accusantium omnis, soluta animi praesentium ipsam fugit? Non ea nisi optio
            dolores.
          </p>
          <a class="my-2 wiew-more" href="#">WIEW MORE</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="news news2">
        <div class="news2-content">
          <div class="buttons">
            <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
            <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
          </div>
          <h1 class="media-room">MEDIA ROOM </h1>
          <div class="img">
            <img src="/Core/img/media.jpg" style="width:500px" alt="">
          </div>
          <p class="texter">London, June 2019 – If you want to enjoy wireless technology while gaming an unnoticeable
            latency is key.
            Sennheiser introduces the GSP 670, Sennheiser's first wireless gaming headset. The GSP 670 gives gamers
            significantly more freedom of movement than wired models. The audio specialist has integrated a proprietary
            low-latency connection that guarantees a reliable and stable transmission with near-zero delay. In addition,
            the GSP 670 offers Sennheiser’s renowned wearing comfort and premium audio performance.

          </p>
          <a class="my-2 wiew-more " href="#">WIEW MORE2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="dots">
        <span class="dot " onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="prev2"></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="next2"></a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Section four -->
  <section id="section-four">
    <div id="section-four-content">
      <h1>CONTACT</h1>
      <div class="IMG">
        <img src="/Core/img/logo.png" style="width: 100px" alt="logo">
      </div>
      <p>Headphone Creative Tehnology LTD</p>
      <p>ADD:No.3 Willow Road London UK Post Code:LO45FR</p>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">
            <p>858-5455-555</p>
            <span><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i></span>
            <p>SERVICE HOTLINE</p>
          </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <p>the_voice@yahoo.com</p>
            <span><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></span>
            <p>E-MAIL</p>
          </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <p>0738-5455-5325</p>
            <span><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i></span>
            <p>TELEPHONE</p>
          </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <p>32 221-5464895</p>
            <span><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i></span>
            <p>FAX</p>
          </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <p>the_voice</p>
            <span><i class="fab fa-skype"></i></span>
            <p>SKYPE</p>
          </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

---

### Aside:

This code is really messy